# Using hyperref, how do I change the links in the document to blue but leaving the TOC black?

Tags: hyperref

Consider:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts, graphicx, verbatim, mathtools,amssymb, amsthm, mathrsfs,amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{rsfso}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel, arrows.meta, positioning, quotes}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,anchorcolor=black,citecolor=black,filecolor=black,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray} 
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
\usepackage[thinc]{esdiff}
\usepackage{ae}
\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=numeric,maxbibnames=200,sortcites=true,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\allowdisplaybreaks


\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\newpage
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[ER]{\nouppercase\leftmark}
\fancyhead[OL]{\nouppercase\rightmark}
\fancyhead[EL,OR]{\thepage}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
%\begin{figure}
%\centering
%\includegraphics[width=9cm]{UoLLogo.png}
%\end{figure}
    \rule[0.5cm]{15cm}{0.1cm} 
\Huge
    {blabla bla}
    \rule{15cm}{0.1cm}
    \\\vspace{3cm}
    {\normalsize \it{Thesis submitted for the degree of}} \\
    {\normalsize \it{Doctor of blabla}} \\
    {\normalsize \it{at the}} \\
    {\normalsize \it{blablabla}}\\
    \vfill
    
\vspace{5cm}
{\normalsize by} \\
{\normalsize bla}\\
{\normalsize bla}\\
{\normalsize University of bla}\\
{\normalsize  bla}\\
\rule{15cm}{0.1cm}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\clearpage
\begin{center}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \textit{bla}
    \vspace*{\fill}
\end{center}

\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\chapter{Abstract}

\clearpage
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\phantomsection%<---
\listoffigures
\clearpage
\phantomsection%<---
\listoftables
\clearpage
\mainmatter

\section{intro}


\begin{equation}\label{a1}
2+2=4
\end{equation}

observe \eqref{a1} is beautfiul.

\section{bla}



\end{document}
```

how can we make the equation one stay in blue but keep the TOC black?

Comment: Your example is not at all minimal. You have way too many unnecessary packages listed in your code. Always try to keep it minimal.

Comment: Also, `typography` tag is really irrelevant. Your question is specifically about hyperlinks, references or at the most about `hyperref` (which you rightly have included).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest this way.

1. Use the `xcolor` package.
2. Use `\usepackage{hyperref}` with the `colorlinks` option.
3. Use `\hypersetup` command and the `linkcolor` parameter with the desired values.

To see how it works, try the following.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}

\tableofcontents

\bigskip

\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}

Look at section no.~\ref{mylab}.

\section{foo}
\label{mylab}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, solved my problem :)